# Regex to model the below mentioned type of expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
| SITE | Morning | Afternoon | Evening | Night |  
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
| Long 144 - Lat 18  | 100 | 150 | 10  | 5 |  
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
| Long 161 - Lat 122 |   100   |   |   | 5 |  
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
| Long 100 - Lat 134 |   100   |   | 5 |   |  
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
| Long 190 - Lat 14  |    |    | 158 |  5  |
```

Since I don't see a pattern I'm stuck on how to model a regular expression to extract the values from site, morning, afternoon, evening and night. For example my regex should be able to scrape ('Long 144 - Lat 18', '100','150','10','5') from the first row and ('Long 161 - Lat 122', '100','','','5') from the second row, so on. I'm able to scrape the 'SITE' column but can't think of a model to scrape the rest. Main thing is I don't have "|", "+" and "NULL" in my data, I just used them here in this question to make it a little clear, they are all replaced with space in original data. Any help is greatly appreciated. Sorry for the ugly pattern, I tried to make it look pretty.
**Edit:** [Data description pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC8Vj.png)

Comment: What  does the data actually look, is it in a file?

Comment: It doesn't have  '|' and '+', just spaces. Yes, it is in a file.

Comment: It is just an empty space.

Comment: can you add an actual line because this seems pretty trivial to solve if I am understanding you correctly

Comment: Long 144 - Lat 18  100 150 10  x  5  
Long 144 - Lat 18  258              x  2  
Long 144 - Lat 18  100        10  x      
Long 144 - Lat 18          220 5   x  2

Comment: Is that one line or more than one?

Comment: These are four lines. Since I can't start a new line I wrote it under one line.

Comment: What's the x here in "Long 144 - Lat 18 100 150 10 `x` 5 Long 144 - Lat 18 258 `x` 2 Long 144 - Lat 18 100 10 `x` Long 144 - Lat 18 220 5 `x` 2 " And, it looks possible that some fields could be missing. If you don't have "NULL", the only thing you can do is something like this..

Comment: You should probably add the data to your question exactly as it is in your file.

Comment: I've uploaded a pic here: http://imgur.com/gallery/TqHWzuS/new

Comment: The 'X' in there is to consider maximum value between evening and night, but I'm not worried about that.

Comment: You can use a code block to format your input data *exactly* as it appears in the picture. No need for confusing +-s or |-s.

Comment: If your input is indeed simple text, then you should [edit] your question and update the way your input is currently displayed. Avinash Raj just put a code block around it; the +, | and NULLs are still there, creating confusing. And while you claim your input is not fixed format, your picture clearly shows it us. When editing your question, *copy-paste* a section of your input, and apply a code block to it (the two braces, "{}").

Answer (score 1):

The data is simply in fixed-position format; that's easy to handle.

You'll want to read each line fully, and then split that line according to the column position. Not by regex or using `.split()`.

E.g., simplistic version:

```
with open("data.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
         longitude = float(line[5:10])
         latitude = float(line[15:20])
         morning = line[25:30]
         # See if there's data, otherwise assign a default
         morning = float(morning) if morning.strip() else 0
         # Ditto for afternoon, evening, night
```

The column limits are obviously chosen at random in this example; it'll be easy to figure them out with the correct data file.

Comment: The data is not in fixed position format, that is the problem here. I apologize for displaying it in that way, my bad. My intention was to display it as clearly as possible. Sorry again.

Comment: Your picture says it is; I don't know how you created that picture, but otherwise you've mangled your input file.